# CSS: make a property ignore the transition time without using jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, css

I recently got into this problem, I have a 'div' element that is set to have:

```
#add-wallet-div {
   width: 10px;
   height: 10px;
   background: blue;
   border-radius: 10px;
   opacity: 0;
   transition: 1s;
}
```

and when I add to this element the 'toggled' class it expand:

```
#add-wallet-div.toggled {
   height: 300px;
   width: 200px;
   opacity: 1;
}
```

The problem here is that I want the opacity to go from a value of 0 to a value of 1 **instantaneously**, but since I have to set transition time to 1s this isn't happening.

I saw a couple of solution to this problem but all of them use **jQuery**, which I'd prefer **not to use**.

I also tried this:

```
#add-wallet-div {
   width: 10px;
   height: 10px;
   background: blue;
   border-radius: 10px;
   opacity: 0;
}

#add-wallet-div.toggled {
   height: 300px;
   width: 200px;
   transition: 1s;
}

#add-wallet-div.toggled2 {
   opacity: 1;
}
```

But nothing changed.

Comment: use, `transition: opacity 1s`, also don't forget vendor specific ones `-webkit-transition`

Comment: @LawrenceCherone it's 2021, no need to prefix `transition` http://shouldiprefix.com/ Or at least in modern development you would use an Autoprefixer that targets Browserslist > n% - so you don't have to think about it any more.

Comment: unfortunately, I have to support older browsers, the kind a nanna uses, so is a habit to add them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found a way to solve this:

```
    #add-wallet-div {
       width: 10px;
       height: 10px;
       background: blue;
       border-radius: 10px;
       opacity: 0;
       transition-duration: 1s;
       transition-property: width, height;
    }

    #add-wallet-div.toggled {
       height: 300px;
       width: 200px;
       opacity: 1;
    }
```

Basically using the 'transition-property' property I tell on wich proprties the transition should have an effect.

Here's a [more in-depth explanation](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_transition-property.asp).

Answer (score 0):

can you explain how is the class toggled??? May be the class `toggled2` is added first and opacity becomes 1 and then class `toggled` is added but since opacity is already 1 , you cannot get required transition effect.